# After i hit enter for the blank page, no process takes place after this. Why is this happening?

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework

[I have attached the screen shot of the command prompt. Here it also gives the info for my current git version, ionic version, node version.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQjlU.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the latest version of node is creating the problem, some of the previous stable version like v8.11.4 works just fine